# Why does pixel binning remove colors and provide monochrome image only with CMOS color cameras?

Tags: usb, camera, rgb, color

Some industrial cameras (astrophotography or microscopy) offer a hardware digital "binning" feature. Indeed, sending uncompressed 10 megapixels x 3 RGB bytes per pixel x 30 frames per second = 858 MB/sec is quite heavy for a monitoring PC, even if the camera is USB3.0!

Vendors usually offer "binning" from 1x1 to 16x16 (ex: with 4x4 horizontal and vertical binning, the image size will be 16 times smaller), but in all cases I have always seen:

> *Note that when using binning greater than 1x1, the image will be monochrome.*

**Question: for which hardware reason do CMOS color cameras produce monochrome image when we use binning/subsampling?** Is it related to Bayer matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an electrical engineering question. Are you sure it shouldn't be on photography.SE?

Comment: @Hearth photography.SE is more on the artistic or technical postprocessing side, but not really on the electronics aspect (Bayer matrix, CMOS sensors, etc.).

Comment: @Hearth I think this is EE. I also think it's just because it's at least three times more circuitry to bin the different colours together than to mash them into a single luminance signal.

Comment: @DKNguyen This might be the answer then... So sad we can't do binning and keep RGB colors :)

Comment: @Basj I don't know what binning is used for but it would seem there is no market need for coloured versions of it.

Comment: @DKNguyen It is used to do a less CPU-intensive camera monitoring than using 800 MB/sec to monitor a 10 megapixel camera at 30 fps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be because of the Bayer (color filter) array, although that depends on the camera manufacturer making a particular set of decisions.

Adjacent pixels have filters in front of them that make each pixel responsive to one set of wavelengths; a full-color image is produced using algorithms (called "demosaicing") that propagate the color values from the pixels that capture that color to neighboring pixels (not always in linear ways; there might be edge-detection or other clever algorithms involved).

If you bin pixels at the stage where they're read out from the sensor, before the demosaicing algorithm runs, then the demosaicing won't work properly, and needs to be bypassed. In the simplest case (an RGBG array and 2x2 binning, or any multiple of 2), the binning perfectly erases the color information because every bin contains all three colors, in the same proportion as every other bin (1R : 2G : 1B). In less-simple cases there could be some residual color-spatial information left after binning, but it would require a different algorithm to resolve, and it would be of poor resolution anyway, and not really worth bothering with.

But couldn't you do the pixel binning *after* the demosaicing? Yes, you could. And if the purpose of binning is to reduce the bandwidth going to the PC, it seems that you should. So why not do that? I've tried to think of a reason, and I can only come up with one sensible one: the manufacturer decided not to implement demosaicing in hardware, to save money — it's done on the PC instead. If that was the case, demosaicing before binning wouldn't be an option, and you'd be stuck with monochrome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I see it's probably done before demosaicing, therefore the color info is lost.
`But couldn't you do the pixel binning after the demosaicing? Yes, you could. And if the purpose of binning is to reduce the bandwidth going to the PC, it seems that you should. So why not do that?` I don't know if it's possible to ask the driver to bin *after* demosaicing the Bayer. Would be interesting!

Comment: Reference: https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=13255&pn=CS895CU, click on *"Specs"* then `Vertical and Horizontal
Digital Binning (c)` `For color cameras, binning greater than 1 x 1 is only available when the camera is operating in unprocessed mode (monochrome).`

Comment: You do not have to bin after debayering.  You can bin at Bayer quad level, combining adjacent green with adjacent green, red with red, and blue with blue. `So why not do that?` Point grey and many other vendors will sell you cameras that do exactly this.

Comment: @Basj That is a budget scientific camera that Thorlabs launched to undercut higher end models.  One of the ways they reduced the price was by omitting features.  If you want those features, pay for them.  Overthinking this or looking for a hardware reason a budget device doesn't support advanced features is nonsense.  It is all price.  Buy a different camera that supports what you need.

Comment: @user1850479 or that, yes :)

Comment: @user1850479 Would you have an idea of model (or brand) that I could look at that would have this feature? I could pass this info to the sourcing team, and then it would save me dozens of hours of headaches for me in the software team :)

Comment: @Basj Point Grey (now FLIR).  Call up some other vendors as well, probably most have options for you, although maybe not every model.

Comment: The On Semi [MT9P031](https://www.onsemi.com/products/sensors/image-sensors/mt9p031) is a 5-megapixel sensor that has been used for many years in many different applications, including in space. Its binning feature preserves the ability to do color.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hardware reason this is done, and not all CMOS cameras revert to monochrome when binning. Most likely the vendor did not expect demand for the feature and so did not implement it.  Particularly for microscopy or industrial uses color sensors are less frequently used, so features specific to color imaging are less likely to be prioritized.